# Condition for horizontal orientation + IOS/android app development

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am creating an ios/android app with phonegap(cordova) framework. My UI code is little bit lacking in horizontal orientation. So, I want to change the look and feel only for horizontal orientation and not for vertical. Is there a condition which i can apply in index.html to achieve this, preferrably in `javascript/jquery`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an event listener for the event onOrientationChange() in which you can probably change the css file which applies in a particular orientation.

```
// create the link tag for the css file in your head section
<HEAD>
<LINK ID="OrientationSpecificCSSTag" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF=""> // keep the href empty, will set later
.....
</HEAD>
```

Now attach the event listener in your javascript file or your script tag

```
// attach the onOrientationChange event listener in your script tag
window.addEventListener( 'onorientationchange', OnOrientationChange, false );
```

Implement the OnOrientationChange function which actually changes the css files according to the orientation

```
function OnOrientationChange()
{
    // case: if portrait
    if( window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 270 )
    {
         document.getElementById('OrientationSpecificCSSTag').HREF = 'landscape.css';
    }
    else
    {
         document.getElementById('OrientationSpecificCSSTag').HREF = 'portrait.css';
    }
}
```